# Interupçoes sistema operacionais

Tags: sistema-operacional

Galera alguem pode me explicar esse IDT[0x21] nos indices dessas structs

Porque 0x21 nos indices?

```
struct IDT_entry IDT[IDT_SIZE];
unsigned long keyboard_address;
unsigned long idt_address;
unsigned long idt_ptr[2];

/* populate IDT entry of keyboard's interrupt */
keyboard_address = (unsigned long)keyboard_handler; 
IDT[0x21].offset_lowerbits = keyboard_address & 0xffff;
IDT[0x21].selector = 0x08; /* KERNEL_CODE_SEGMENT_OFFSET */
IDT[0x21].zero = 0;
IDT[0x21].type_attr = 0x8e; /* INTERRUPT_GATE */
IDT[0x21].offset_higherbits = (keyboard_address & 0xffff0000) >> 16;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os processadores possuem dois PICs (*Programmable Interrupt Controller*). O primeiro deles cuida das interrupções de IRQ0 a IRQ7, e o outro cuida do IRQ8 até IRQ15.

O primeiro usa a porta `0x20` para *Command* (ICW) e `0x21` para *Data*. O segundo usa as portas `0xA0` e `0xA1`.

Você está mexendo com as interrupções do teclado (IRQ1), então vai mexer com o primeiro PIC (comando na porta `0x20` e dados na porta `0x21`).

Atualização: Achei esse link (em inglês), que explica bem: http://arjunsreedharan.org/post/99370248137/kernel-201-lets-write-a-kernel-with-keyboard